# Librosa - Audio Spectrogram/Frequency Bins to Spectrum

Tags: python, audio, librosa, spectrogram

I've read around for several days but haven't been to find a solution... I'm able to build Librosa spectrograms and extract amplitude/frequency data using the following:

```
audio, sr = librosa.load('short_piano melody_keyCmin_110bpm.wav', sr = 22500)
spectrum = librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=2048, window=scipy.signal.windows.hamming)
D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(spectrum), ref=np.max)
n = D.shape[0]
Nfft = 1+2*(n-1)
freq_bins = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=Nfft)
```

However, I cannot turn the data in D and freq_bins back into a spectrum. Once I am able to do this I can convert the new spectrum into a .wav file and listen to my reconstructed audio... Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: To turn an stft-based spectrum back into an audio signal, you should use [istft](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.istft.html). Note that to convert back to the time domain, you need a *complex-valued* spectrum, not just the *absolute* one. However, you could simply try to use the phase from the original signal. Also note that depending on what you want to do, the [cqt](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.cqt.html) and [icqt](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.icqt.html), might be a better choice.

Comment: @Hendrik Thank you for your response! I am aware of these methods but do not know how to convert amplitudes into a spectrum... Not sure if it's even possible but it seems like it should be some other kind of inverse?

Comment: Amplitudes are converted to a spectrum using `stft`. It gives you a complex valued spectrum. Preserve the phase and manipulate the magnitude of those values. Then convert back using `istft`. The conversion back relies on the [Griffin/Lim](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1172092)-paper. It's a classic, so there are plenty of easy to follow explanations on the web. Good luck!

Comment: Here's a better link to the paper: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.331.7151&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get your question right, you want to reconstruct the real/imaginary spectrum from your magnitude values. You will need the phase component for that, then its all simple complex number arithmetic. You should be aware that the output of an STFT is an array of complex numbers, and the amplitude is the absulute value of each number, while the phase is the angle of each number

Here´s an example of a time-domain signal transformed to magnitude/phase and back without modifying it:

```
% get the complex valued spectrum from a sample
spectrum = librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=2048,window=scipy.signal.windows.hamming) 

# get magnitude and phase from the complex numbers
magnitude = np.abs(spectrum)
phase = np.angle(spectrum)

# reconstruct real/imaginary parts from magnitude and phase
spectrum = magnitude * np.exp(1j*phase)

# transform back to time-domain
```

In your case, you should first convert the db-values back to amplitude values, of course. Even having no experience with librosa, I´m sure that there is also a function for that.